# Problem with \chapter* and fancyhdr

Tags: table-of-contents, chapters, fancyhdr

I'm having a problem with `\chapter*{}` and `fancyhdr`. I want to start the first chapter of my thesis with a introduction section, appearing in the TOC but without numeration, that's why I use:

```
\chapter*{Introduccion}
```

and

```
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Introduccion}
```

at the beginning of the `Introduccion.tex` file, but I don't know why, the `fancyhdr` header shows "list of tables" instead of "Introduccion"!

(the list of tables is immediately before the introduction).

Here is my code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}
%
\usepackage[bottom=25mm,top=25mm, left=30mm, right=25mm]{geometry}
%
\parskip=8pt
%
\widowpenalty=10000
\clubpenalty=10000
%
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
\usepackage{morefloats}
%
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage[pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
    bookmarks=true,         % barra de marcadores
    unicode=false,          % caracteres non-Latin en marcadores de Acrobat
    pdftoolbar=true,        % mostrar barra de herramientas de Acrobat
    pdfmenubar=true,        % mostrar menú de Acrobat
    pdffitwindow=false,     % ajustar ventana al ancho de página
    pdfstartview={FitH},    % ajustar documento al ancho de página
    pdftitle={Memoria PFC}, % título
    pdfauthor={},           % autor
    pdfsubject={},          % tema del documento
    pdfcreator={},          % generador del documento
    pdfproducer={},         % productor del documento
    pdfkeywords={},         % lista de palabras clave
    pdfnewwindow=true,      % enlaces en una nueva ventana
    colorlinks=true,        % false: enlaces en caja; true: enlaces coloreados
    linkcolor=blue,         % color de enlaces internos
    citecolor=green,        % color de enlaces a bibliografía
    filecolor=magenta,      % color de enlaces a ficheros
    urlcolor=blue           % color de enlaces externos
}
%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[EL]{\nouppercase\leftmark}
\fancyhead[OR]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancyhead[ER,OL]{\thepage}
%
\makeatletter
%
\def\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside \ifodd\c@page\else
  \hbox{}
  \thispagestyle{empty}
  \newpage
  \if@twocolumn\hbox{}\newpage\fi\fi\fi}
\makeatother
%
\begin{document}
%
\pagenumbering{gobble} % Las primeras paginas no quiero que se numeren
%
\includepdf[pages={-}]{./Archivos/Portada_PFCccompleto.pdf}
\input{./Archivos/Capitulos/pfc_dedicatoria}
\input{./Archivos/Capitulos/pfc_agradecimientos}
\include{./Archivos/Capitulos/pfc_abreviaturas}
%
% FRONTMATTER: TOC, LOF, LOT 
\frontmatter
%
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
%
% MAINMATTER
%
\mainmatter
\include{./Archivos/Capitulos/pfc_intro}
\include{./Archivos/Capitulos/pfc_main_010}
...
%
```

Comment: This is a very common problem. Add `\markboth{Introduccion}{Introduccion}` after `\chapter*{Introduccion}`. By the way, instead of redefining `\cleardoublepage`, you can add `\usepackage{emptypage}`

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: It might already help if you move the introduction to the `\frontmatter` and use a normal `\chapter`. An alternative could be to use a class and »scrpage2« from »[KOMA-Script](http://ctan.org/pkg/KOMA-Script)« and use its `\addchap` command.

Answer (score 11):

This is a very common problem. The `\chapter*` command doesn't update the marks that are used for the headers, while `\listoftables` does.

So the result is that after

```
\mainmatter
\chapter*{Introduccion}
```

The simplest and more effective remedy is to issue

```
\markboth{Introduccion}{Introduccion}
```

since you're removing the usual uppercasing done by the `book` class; you could also, for doing like the `\listof...` commands, type

```
\markboth{\MakeUppercase{Introduccion}}{\MakeUppercase{Introduccion}}
```

so the style will be the same even if you eventually decide not to use `fancyhdr`.

However, the best option, in my opinion, is to number also the introduction and forget about all these problems.

---

A couple of words about your style. I prefer to have a package loading section and then a setup section in the preamble. Also, `pdftex` should not be passed to `graphicx`. Instead of redefining `\cleardoublepage` it's simpler to load the `emptypage` package.

I removed the settings to `\clubpenalty` and `\widowpenalty` to 10000, because this doesn't really solve the problems with club and widow lines. Reinstate them, if you prefer. Also setting a nonzero parskip should be avoided: it hinders readability rather than enhancing it, particularly in presence of short paragraphs, producing loads of white strips on the page.

Last, I added `headheight=14.5pt` as requested by `fancyhdr`.

Here's an edited version (`kantlipsum` is just for producing some nonsense text).

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage[
  bottom=25mm,
  top=25mm,
  left=30mm,
  right=25mm,
  headheight=14.5pt,
]{geometry}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}

\usepackage{kantlipsum} % for populating the document

\usepackage{morefloats}
\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage[pagebackref=true]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{%
    bookmarks=true,         % barra de marcadores
    unicode=false,          % caracteres non-Latin en marcadores de Acrobat
    pdftoolbar=true,        % mostrar barra de herramientas de Acrobat
    pdfmenubar=true,        % mostrar menú de Acrobat
    pdffitwindow=false,     % ajustar ventana al ancho de página
    pdfstartview={FitH},    % ajustar documento al ancho de página
    pdftitle={Memoria PFC}, % título
    pdfauthor={},           % autor
    pdfsubject={},          % tema del documento
    pdfcreator={},          % generador del documento
    pdfproducer={},         % productor del documento
    pdfkeywords={},         % lista de palabras clave
    pdfnewwindow=true,      % enlaces en una nueva ventana
    colorlinks=true,        % false: enlaces en caja; true: enlaces coloreados
    linkcolor=blue,         % color de enlaces internos
    citecolor=green,        % color de enlaces a bibliografía
    filecolor=magenta,      % color de enlaces a ficheros
    urlcolor=blue           % color de enlaces externos
}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[EL]{\nouppercase\leftmark} 
\fancyhead[OR]{\nouppercase\rightmark}
\fancyhead[ER,OL]{\thepage}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\mainmatter

\chapter*{Introduccion}
\markboth{Introduccion}{Introduccion}

\kant

\chapter{Abc}

\section{Def}

\kant

\begin{table}
\caption{X}
\end{table}

\begin{figure}
\caption{Y}
\end{figure}

\kant

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try de-activating properties that you define of `fancyhdr` package, then put your chapter and your text and finally activates fancy properties again, but you have to be careful locating the lines to reactivate it:

```
\listoftables  
\fancyhf{} % sets both header and footer to nothing
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}

\chapter*{my-chapter-name}
\blindtext   
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%% NOTE: PAY ATTENTION HERE %%%%%%%%%%
%%%%
%%%%    If the text after the '\chapter*{my-chapter-name}':
%%%%    is more than one page, the lines after this note  should 
%%%%    be exactly after the first paragraph of the second page
%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    
\pagestyle{fancy}                   
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyhead[L]{\scriptsize \leftmark}
\fancyfoot[L]{\scriptsize \rightmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.5pt}
```

Comment: Note that this removes the header altogether.

Comment: Thanks for the replay and correction, my native language is spanish, but I try my best in English